# CoreGraphics Circle Animation Wrong Duration

Tags: ios, animation, core-graphics, duration

**Edit: I think the best is to convert the code to CoreAnimation. How would this code be converted to that method? I believe the issue is the fact that there is a difference in device FPS.**

I have been searching for a custom progress circle for iOS and come across this library: https://github.com/Eclair/CircleProgressBar

I have noticed however that there is a bug whenever animating for about over 5 seconds. The animation of the circle is slower than it should be. For example: I animate the circle to 100% completed in 30 seconds however it only reaches like 78% in that time period (the "Done" label is visible after a NSTimer of 30 seconds). Check out this image I took in a demo project I made:
[image]

This is the code to make the circle:

```
- (void)drawProgressBar:(CGContextRef)context progressAngle:(CGFloat)progressAngle center:(CGPoint)center radius:(CGFloat)radius {
    CGFloat barWidth = self.progressBarWidthForDrawing;
    if (barWidth > radius) {
        barWidth = radius;
    }

    CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, self.progressBarProgressColorForDrawing.CGColor);
    CGContextBeginPath(context);
    CGContextAddArc(context, center.x, center.y, radius, DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(_startAngle), DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(progressAngle), 0);
    CGContextAddArc(context, center.x, center.y, radius - barWidth, DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(progressAngle), DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(_startAngle), 1);
    CGContextClosePath(context);
    CGContextFillPath(context);

    CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, self.progressBarTrackColorForDrawing.CGColor);
    CGContextBeginPath(context);
    CGContextAddArc(context, center.x, center.y, radius, DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(progressAngle), DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(_startAngle + 360), 0);
    CGContextAddArc(context, center.x, center.y, radius - barWidth, DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(_startAngle + 360), DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(progressAngle), 1);
    CGContextClosePath(context);
    CGContextFillPath(context);
}
```

This is the code that animates the circle:

```
- (void)animateProgressBarChangeFrom:(CGFloat)startProgress to:(CGFloat)endProgress duration:(CGFloat)duration {
    _currentAnimationProgress = _startProgress = startProgress;
    _endProgress = endProgress;

    _animationProgressStep = (_endProgress - _startProgress) * AnimationChangeTimeStep / duration;

    _animationTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:AnimationChangeTimeStep target:self selector:@selector(updateProgressBarForAnimation) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
    [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] addTimer:_animationTimer forMode:NSRunLoopCommonModes];
}

- (void)updateProgressBarForAnimation {
    _currentAnimationProgress += _animationProgressStep;
    _progress = _currentAnimationProgress;
    if ((_animationProgressStep > 0 && _currentAnimationProgress >= _endProgress) || (_animationProgressStep < 0 && _currentAnimationProgress <= _endProgress)) {
        [_animationTimer invalidate];
        _animationTimer = nil;
        _progress = _endProgress;
    }
    [self setNeedsDisplay];
}
```

Is there anything here that looks wrong? Is there a better way to animate the circle? I would ideally want it to animate with the correct duration and I am just not that familiar in how to fix this.

Demo Project to showcase issue:
https://ufile.io/8pkt5

Comment: I just grabbed that "Eclair/CircleProgressBar" repo, changed the "Increase" button to go directly to 100% in 30-seconds - `[_circleProgressBar setProgress:1.0f animated:YES duration:30.0];` - and it worked fine. Did you do something different?

Comment: @DonMag The issue isn't that it gets to 100%, the problem is that it takes actually longer than 30 seconds. I will attach a demo project here in a minute to showcase the issue. Edit: Added link

Comment: Hmmm... I downloaded your edited project... ran it on the simulator... watched it along with timing it on a physical clock... "Done" label popped up right at 100%, which was right at 30 seconds on the physical clock. Then built and ran it on a physical 7+ ... same (correct) results.

Comment: @DonMag Which iOS version and MacOS version are you running? I just re-ran the sample project on an iOS 10.2.2 iPhone 6 Plus and I still see the issue. I even ran a timer next to me to double check and saw the problem occur.

Comment: I can't imagine it's due to version diffs, but... iMac running El Cap 10.11.6 Simulator @ 10.2, Xcode 8.2.1, iPhone 7+ 10.2.1, iPad Air 10.2.1.. and just for the heck of it ran on Sim iPhone 6 @ 9.3 (needed minor code edit)... All with consistent, accurate results.

Comment: @DonMag Its very odd. I just tested on the simulator and it worked however on my device it has the issue. Is it a iOS 10.3 vs iOS 10.3.1 issue? Maybe is there some better way of animating?

Comment: Try rebooting your device? Hard to say... the "animation" - as you've seen - is very simple.. just a timer calling setNeedsDisplay.

Comment: @DonMag Ideally I would like to transition the code to CoreAnimation. I think the problem is the difference in the FPS and the number of times drawRect gets called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically drawRect method works on main thread and since you're using too small AnimationChangeTimeStep:

```
const CGFloat AnimationChangeTimeStep = 0.01f;
```

It's 100 frames per second, which is too much and drawRect blocks main thread and animation timer attached to that thread, so repeats of animation timer fires not immediately but after all current drawRect calls finished. 
So to fix your problem just decrease AnimationChangeTimeStep and make it equal to frame rate 30 fps:

```
const CGFloat AnimationChangeTimeStep = 1/30.0f;
```